# Leaflet not taking all data when extending markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have extended my leaflet object by setting two now attributes:
    - Value
    - Name

```
var customMarker = L.Marker.extend({
                options: {
                name: '',
                value: ''
                }
             });
```

Then I call this method:

```
L.geoJson(centroids,{
              pointToLayer: function(feature,geometry){
                var marker = new customMarker(geometry);
                marker.value = donnees[feature.properties.Index];
                marker.name = feature.properties.Index;
                console.log("name : "+marker.name+" volume : "+marker.volume)
                return marker;
              }
        });
```

But I noticed that not all the marker.value are stored in my markers. some have unidentified as value.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is creating new options in your extended L.Marker. You can set options during instanciation of your marker. Simple example:

```
// Extending marker with custom option
L.Marker.Custom = L.Marker.extend({
     options: {
          customValue: false
     }
});

// Instanciating without custom option:
var marker = new L.Marker.Custom([0,0]);
console.log(marker.options.customValue); //false

// Instanciating with custom option:
var marker = new L.Marker.Custom([0,0], {
    customValue: true
});
console.log(marker.options.customValue); //true
```

Thing is, that if you only need to have some custom options,  there is no need to extend L.Marker but you can simply instanciate L.Marker with a custom option:

```
// Instanciating regular L.Marker with custom option:
var marker = new L.Marker([0,0], {
    customValue: true
});
console.log(marker.options.customValue); //true
```

You only need to extend L.Marker when you need a default value for your custom option.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just JS issue. In your `donnes` array you don't have all the indexes you are trying to access

`marker.value = donnees[feature.properties.Index];`

that's why you get undefined in `marker.value`
Check if `donnees[feature.properties.Index]` doesn't give you undefined and only then return a proper marker